# I seem to have disabled the ~ (tilde) on a Touchbar MacBook Pro?

Tags: macos, mac, macbook-pro

I have the original US keyboard setting and have not changed any settings. Somehow I seemed to have pressed the wrong combinations of keys that resulted in the ~ (tilde) character being disabled. If you are wondering how the hell i am typing it well i am just copy pasting it!

My girlfriend has the same computer and it works just fine and we have the same settings....any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

For US international keyboard first press `option` + `n` then press `spacebar`.